# Issue while passing a parameter to HQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

> Error : bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

While passing `varchar(16)` as a parameter in HQL.

```
hive --hivevar id_variable_type="${id_variable_type}" -f $HIVE_SCRIPT_DIR/tds_validation.hql
```

Here the value of `id_variable_type` is `Varchar(16)`.

Code where it is used:

```
SELECT  cast(customer_id as ${hivevar:id_variable_type}) as 
,run_date 
FROM ABCXXXX;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take off **hivevar** from **`${hivevar:id_variable_type}`** and replace **`${id_variable_type}`**

***Sample script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
id_variable_type="varchar(16)"
echo $id_variable_type
hive --hivevar id_variable_type="${id_variable_type}" -e "select cast(string('hive variables substitution') as ${id_variable_type})"
```

***Output:***

```
hive variables s
```

Comment: In your example ${id_variable_type} is direct a shell variable, not variable passed to the hive command line. You can check it by removing this `--hivevar id_variable_type="${id_variable_type}"` from command line. And it will work.